# SELECT INTO query to create MEMORY_OPTIMIZED table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

is it possible to generate a MEMORY_OPTIMIZED table with an SELECT INTO statement?
Something like:

```
SELECT *
INTO MemoryOptimizedTargetTable
FROM SourceTable;
```

Or at least convert the target after the SELECT INTO with an ALTER statement?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

With [SQL Server 2017 it will be possible to specify a *filegroup*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql), but that's as far as it goes into customizing the created table.

Since `SELECT ... INTO ...` is equivalent to `CREATE TABLE`, to be fully customizable it would require all options CREATE TABLE has. This is not really feasible. Once you realizE that in effect you are creating a table and inserting rows into it, why not do just that?

```
CREATE TABLE ...
INSERT ... SELECT ...
```